# Format string placeholders

Tags: c#, formatting

Do format string placeholders have a more technical name?

For example,

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
Console.WriteLine("The current year is {0}.", currentYear);
```

If you were reading this code out loud, or to yourself, how do you read the placeholder? Is there a correct term for representing them?

Comment: Are you talking about [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes. If you were to read that 2nd line to yourself or someone else, how would you read the `'{0}'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `Format Item`.  Check [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).